# Finding maximum product of two columns after groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like the one in the following :

```
    item    width   length
0   X        4        1
1   F       15        4
2   R        6        3
3   X        3        10
4   F       10        19
```

For every item, I want to list width and length of the longest item. I tried using `df.groupby("item").max()` but it gives me the following dataframe which is wrong:

```
  item  width       length
    F        15       19
    R        6        3
    X        4        10
```

What I expect is the following dataframe:

```
  item    width     length
    F        10       19
    R        6        3
    X        3        10
```

Comment: @Prune I hope the extract information would provide sufficient context for my question

Comment: @dawg I added more information, hope it helps

Comment: well it's exactly what I expect... take F, width has two values 10&15.  15 is selected.  length has two values 4&19, 19 is selected.   That's what arithmetic max is.  If you mean the max of the product,  that's a different function....

Answer (score 0):

Given (note -- row 0 is different than your example):

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'item':['X','F','R','X','F'], 'width':[60,15,6,3,10],'length':[1,4,3,10,19]})
>>> df
  item  width  length
0    X     60       1
1    F     15       4
2    R      6       3
3    X      3      10
4    F     10      19
```

It is a little unclear if you are looking for the max solely by max length or by area (width * length). Either way, the method is similar.

If you want the max by length, do this:

```
>>> df[df.groupby(['item'])['length'].transform(max)==df['length']]
  item  width  length
2    R      6       3
3    X      3      10
4    F     10      19
```

If you are really asking for a `max` that is the product of the two columns, you add `area` as the product of width * length:

```
>>> df['area']=df['width']*df['length']
```

NOW you can groupby and use `max` against the value in `area`:

```
>>> df[df.groupby(['item'])['area'].transform(max)==df['area']]
  item  width  length  area
0    X     60       1    60
2    R      6       3    18
4    F     10      19   190
```